# Question about asymptotic direction

Tags: differential-geometry

I'd like a hint for the following question:
Show that in a elliptic point, principal directions bisects asymptotic directions.
thanks.

Comment: How do you define "elliptic points", "principal directions", and "asymptotic directions"? What book are you using to learn differential geometry?

Comment: I'm using Manfredo's book(Portuguese version) but there is a english version of it.Elliptic points are points whose Gaussian curvature is always positive, principal direction is a line generated by the eigenvectors of the self-adjoint transformation $DN_p$, asymptotic direction is a line generated by a vector which is tangent to a curve whose normal curvature is zero.I tried to use Euler's formula but get no result.

Answer (score 3):

Elliptic points do not have asymptotic directions, because the principal directions point in the directions in which the normal curvature obtains its maximum $k_1$ and minimum $k_2$.
The curvature of a surface is $K=(k_1)(k_2)$. So if at an elliptic ($K>0$) point you have a direction for which the normal curvature is zero then $k_2$ must be zero, and you arrive to a contradiction.